# how to update iptables docker specific only?

Tags: iptables, docker

I have got below rules present on a docker container in one server. There is a separate chain called DOCKER

```
iptables -L
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             112.13.0.4           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             112.13.0.4           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             112.13.0.4           tcp dpt:ssh
```

I need to add exact same rules on another container on a different server. Basically i am trying to expose ports 80, 443 and 22 to the intranet and I have no idea how to do so. I tried looking into iptables documentation but nothing seems straightforward. My question is how do I add above rules to iptables without disturbing existing rules?

Comment: The DOCKER chain is managed by docker itself.  https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/ Have you checked the content of your `Dockerfile` for the container with existing iptables rules?  See also [docker getting started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/)

Comment: Exporting container ports to the host's network, is something docker can do for you: see option `--publish`, of docker `run` / `create`.